# Visualisation of feedback loops in a directed graph

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, manipulate, visualization

Here are the nodes (vertices) of my graph:

```
a = 
  {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 6}, {2, 6}, {3, 8}, {3, 11}, {4, 8}, {5, 2}, 
   {5, 6}, {5, 8}, {6, 8}, {6, 10}, {6, 11}, {7, 2}, {7, 6}, {8, 9}, {8, 11}, 
   {9, 6}, {10, 2}, {10, 9}, {11, 3}, {11, 4}, {11, 9}, {11, 10}};
```

First, I need to find the all feedback loops of a graph which has directed edges. For this I have tried the following code:

```
cycles[a_] := 
  Module[{f, edges = Rule @@@ a // Dispatch}, 
    f[x_, b___, x_] := {{x, b, x}};
    f[___, x_, ___, x_] = {};
    f[c___, v_] := Join @@ (f[c, v, #] & /@ ReplaceList[v, edges]);
    Join @@ f /@ Union @@ a]
cycles[a];
```

which gives me probably individual feedback loops:

> ```
> {{2, 6, 8, 11, 10, 2}, {2, 6, 10, 2}, {2, 6, 11, 10, 2}, {3, 8, 9, 6, 11, 3}, 
>  {3, 8, 11, 3}, {3, 11, 3}, {4, 8, 9, 6, 11, 4}, {4, 8, 11, 4}, {6, 8, 9, 6}, 
>  {6, 8, 11, 9, 6}, {6, 8, 11, 10, 2, 6}, {6, 8, 11,10, 9, 6}, {6, 10, 2, 6}, 
>  {6, 10, 9, 6}, {6, 11, 3, 8, 9, 6}, {6, 11, 4, 8, 9, 6}, {6, 11, 9, 6}, 
>  {6, 11, 10, 2, 6}, {6, 11, 10, 9, 6}, {8, 9, 6, 8}, {8, 9, 6, 11, 3, 8}, 
>  {8, 9, 6, 11, 4, 8}, {8, 11, 3, 8}, {8, 11, 4, 8}, {8, 11, 9, 6, 8}, 
>  {8, 11, 10, 2, 6, 8}, {8, 11, 10, 9, 6, 8}, {9, 6, 8, 9}, {9, 6, 8, 11, 9}, 
>  {9, 6, 8, 11, 10, 9}, {9, 6, 10, 9}, {9, 6, 11, 3, 8, 9}, {9, 6, 11, 4, 8, 9}, 
>  {9, 6, 11, 9}, {9, 6, 11, 10, 9}, {10, 2, 6, 8, 11, 10}, {10, 2, 6, 10}, 
>  {10, 2, 6, 11, 10}, {10, 9, 6, 8, 11, 10}, {10, 9, 6, 10}, {10,9, 6, 11, 10}, 
>  {11, 3, 8, 9, 6, 11}, {11, 3, 8, 11}, {11, 3, 11}, {11, 4, 8, 9, 6, 11}, 
>  {11, 4, 8, 11}, {11, 9, 6, 8, 11}, {11, 9, 6, 11}, {11, 10, 2, 6, 8, 11}, 
>  {11, 10, 2, 6, 11}, {11, 10, 9, 6, 8, 11}, {11, 10, 9, 6, 11}}
> ```

My main question is: How can I visualise all individual feedback loops of a graph? For example like this:

[image]

Comment: The [IGraph/M package](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM) has the `IGFeedbackArcSet` function, which may be of use for problems like this.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to write code to find cycles. There is a built-in function for that (`FindCycle`) Besides, using pattern matching for this goal as you did is bound to be rather slow.

For visualization of the cycles you can use `HighlightGraph`.

```
g = Graph[Rule @@@ a, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
cycles = FindCycle[g, Infinity, 99999]
Manipulate[
   HighlightGraph[g, cycles[[i]]],
   {{i, 1, "Cycle"}, 1, Length@cycles, 1}
];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]